# Calling UI functions outside of MainActivity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have written UI functions in the MainActivity.java (shown below). Now, due to design issues, my requirement is to separate these functions from `MainActivity.java` and write into other file and, then these functions will interact with UI elements.  How can I separate UI functions from `MainActivity.java`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }   

    // There is "Off" button On UI. Onclick event of the button, this function
    // is called. 
    public void OffCommandInterface(View view) {

    }

    // There is "SetTemp" button On UI. Onclick event of the button, 
    //this function reads data from textbox and send data to other module.
    public void SetTempCommandInterface(View view) {

    }

    // There is "SetTemp" button On UI. Onclick event of the button, 
    //this function reads data from textbox and send data to other module.  
    public void profileRequestInterface(View view){         

    }
}
```

I am attaching activity_main.xml file for the reference.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >          

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:onClick="profileRequestInterface"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Switch Off Heater"
        android:onClick="OffCommandInterface" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_temp"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/temp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:onClick="SetTempCommandInterface"
            android:text="SetTemp" />
    </LinearLayout>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: create another class and call those functions from your `onClick()`s? Your question is quite broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you declared your Button's onClick as part of layout xml its hard to separate out from Activity class scope.

When you declare your view's onClick as layout xml, it will attached with the Activity who called `setContentView()` on that layout. So you have to define your all Button's click method in Activity itself.

Now If you want to separate out this logic as design pattern issue, than remove `onClick` from xml layout file, create custom onClick listener as different java class and override onClick in that class, define your button's in `onCreate()` of Activity and set custom onClick listener to those buttons.

Example: (This is the just example, you can change with your code and use case)

```
public class CustomOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

 private Context appContext;
 public CustomOnClickListener(Context context)
 {
    appContext = context;
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
   switch(arg0.getId())
   {
    case R.id.button1:
    // There is "Off" button On UI. Onclick event of the button, this function
    // is called. 
    break;
   }

  }
}
```

Now, in your Activity,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonOff;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new CustomOnClickListener(this));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  for the pointer! For me, Button's onClick as part of layout xml file is  NOT MANDATORY.  I can change my activity_main.xml file.  Could you please advice with a code for more clarity ?

Comment: This solution works now. Many thanks for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 1):

You can start by removing `android:onClick` from your XML and handling it in the code. I never understood this practice other than for learning purposes. This should get you started.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                this.OffCommandInterface();
                break;
            default:
                break;
    }

    private void OffCommandInterface() { }
    private void SetTempCommandInterface() { }
    private void profileRequestInterface() { }
}
```